# Test if a function was called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a simple React hook:

```
const useHook = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
   }, []);

   const handleClick = () => {};

   return null;
};
```

Am I able to somehow test if the `handleClick` function was called on `click` event?

I can of course simulate `click` event in Jest. However how to check if this fn was called?

Comment: Do you need to know the type of event, or do you just need to know if the function was called from code or called from an event?

Comment: You don't have access to that function, it's an internal detail of the hook. Presumably the actual handler _isn't_ empty, so test the behaviour not the implementation - what's it supposed to _do_ on that click?

Comment: add your test file, please.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, it looks like I will have to test the side effects of the fn call, not the fn call itself, thanks

Answer (score -1):

How about using a count wrapper ?

```js
function countFn(fn) {
    let wrapper = function() {
        wrapper.called ++;
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    wrapper.called = 0;
    return wrapper;
}

const handleClick = countFn((e) => {console.log(e)});

handleClick(1);
handleClick(2);
handleClick(3);

console.log(`handleClick called ${handleClick.called} times`);
```

```
1
2
3
handleClick called 3 times
```